# Updating UI from another thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

We have an issue with an application where we are making a call to an asynchronous process on LostFocus of a TextBox, the asyncronous process then needs to be able to update the main form UI (or display a dialog from the main form UI) while running asynchronously.

We have thought about call backs and having it truely asynchronous but we need everything to execute in the correct order and this is for a data entry system where speed and accuracy of data entry is important.

Example code shows what we are trying to do and if you switch to BeginInvoke the order of processing is not correct.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus

    ' execute the server subroutine
    Dim dlgt As New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.AsyncProcess)

    TextBox1.Text = "1"
    ' textbox should say 1

    ' call the server subroutine asynchronously, so the main thread is free
    Dim ar As IAsyncResult = dlgt.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)

    While ar.IsCompleted = False
        ' Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    ' textbox should now say 2

    TextBox1.Text = "3"
    ' textbox should now say 3
End Sub

Public Sub AsyncProcess()
    UpdateTextBox()
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateTextBox()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateTextBox), "2")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "2"
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Does anyone know how we can invoke something else on the main form thread while is is still busy processing the LostFocus event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code deadlocks without DoEvents, the Invoke() call cannot complete while the UI thread is spinning on IsCompleted.  Using BeginInvoke() instead will always display "2" after "3".  The code is too mysterious to propose an alternative.

Comment: why bother with displaying the 2 ?? the 3 will erase it almost instantly.

Comment: @Vincent Piel - I think he's just trying to illustrate that he wants to be able to update the UI from the background thread, and he wants things to happen in a certain order.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  You can use this class to do long-running tasks in the background and report status back to your UI through events.  The class supports a "ProgressChanged" event and a "RunWorkerCompleted" event.  I've included some example code below to show how to use it to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, 
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus

        TextBox1.Text = "1"

        ' Execute the long-running task in the background
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, 
        ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        ' Do your heavy lifting in this method; report progress as needed by 
        ' calling ReportProgress, which will in turn call Progress_Changed
        ' safely on the UI thread.  (DO NOT update the UI directly from here.)

        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        ' Simulate processing for a second
        Thread.Sleep(1000)

        ' Report progress to the UI (the first arg is the percentage complete;
        ' the secong arg can be a string or any object)
        worker.ReportProgress(50, "2")

        ' Simulate processing for another second
        Thread.Sleep(1000)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
        ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) 
        Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

        ' Update the UI with progress from the background task
        TextBox1.Text = CType(e.UserState, String)

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) 
        Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        ' Update the UI when the background task is finished
        TextBox1.Text = "3"

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: wouldn't this be exactly the same as doing a BeginInvoke? There is no guarantee that the RunWorkerCompleted Event is going to fire before changing the text to "3"... therefore the final value would end up being "2" and not "3"

Comment: No, what you'd need to do is change your code around slightly: do the "before" processing (the "1") in the TextBox_LostFocus event and launch the background worker (as you are now); do the "during" updates (the "2") in the ProgressChanged event, then finally do any "after" processing (the "3") in the RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: The above solution would work... however the existing project is rather large where this sort of solution would not be feasible. The example posted is a very over simplified version of the issue to illustrate the problems. Ideally looking into a queue/event based solution?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what makes this idea infeasable? The more details you can provide about the problem you're trying to solve, the better chance I or someone else will be able to offer a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to not try to wait for the method to finish synchronously.  Change the rest of the LostFocus handler method that you want to implement after the async call into a callback and pass it to `BeginInvoke`.  This allows the UI thread to stay responsive while maintaining order of operations.